# Wifi Neighbor Triangulation

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, signal-strength

Is it possible to discover signal strength between two devices that are connected to the same network?

**Devices**

A. Cell Phone WiFi
   B. WiFi enabled device
   C. Wireless Router

Both A & B are connected to C on the same network. I would like to be able to discover the relative signal strength between A and B.

The goal is to enable B detect when A appears to perform an action like turn on a light switch or a coffeemaker.

My current research shows this is not possible unless I add a separate WiFi / detector to B.

Comment: Something with shorter range like bluetooth may work better here.

Comment: Someone had similar ideas to what you wrote, but instead of using WiFi Signal to check for the existence of Device A and B, they used Fixed IP address. You can have reserved DHCP addressing for both device A and B, so if A comes within range of C, and get the IP, B will periodically ping A every.. say few seconds. If ping failed, then keep going. If ping returns a reply (means A is around), do your action. And pause the ping for a few minutes to assume that A will be around for a while. Or the bluetooth method as per Journeyman Geek would also be a good idea.

Comment: @Darius, thanks, but I'm not only looking for existence, I'm looking for relative distance as well as existence.

Comment: Have you considered using NFC tags around the house? You can use the tag somewhere near the B device, and when your phone swipes near the tag, your phone sees the NFC, and do some action (send command over network from A to B to do something).